# Binary classifier for binary and non-interacting features. Is linear SVM applicable?

Tags: machine-learning, binary-data

I have a binary data set and these features do not interact, e.g., combinations of features are not a descriptor. Labels are also binary as well. I used decision tree which looks at the effect of combined features. As expected, decision tree ended up being a long line without any branch. So, in principle, I need a classifier that is simpler than decision tree that makes yes/no rules based on individual features. What would be a good classifier for this problem?

EDIT: Doing more search.. Linear support vector machine [SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) seems like a good choice. Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can use logistic regression. If you are using SAS, here is the code to use logistic regression in SAS.

proc logistic data = a;
class a(ref='no') b(ref='no') b(ref='no') b(ref='no')/param=ref;
freq count;
model outputv(event='yes')= a b c d;
output out = out pred=pred;
run;

data aout; set out;
if pred < 0.40 then yhat=0;
if pred >= 0.40 then yhat=1;
run;

proc freq data= aout;
table outputv*yhat;
weight count;
run;